# Loop with StateT: Why this loop doesn't loop

Tags: haskell

I don't understand why this code does loop only once then exit ?
in Ghci I can answer only to the first loop then it seems the variable cont is set to false and I don't have the prompt to answer.

The result is:

```
*Main> testLoop1 td10
test
Do you want to continue? (y/N)
y
we continue
test
Do you want to continue? (y/N)
We stop
```

---

code:

```
type TDeckSTIO    = StateT TableDecks IO

continue = do
putStrLn "Do you want to continue? (y/N)"
c <- getChar
return $ c == 'y'


loop1 :: TDeckSTIO () 
loop1 = do 
    liftIO $ putStrLn "test"
    cont<- liftIO continue 
    if cont
    then do 
        liftIO $ putStrLn "we continue"
        liftIO $ testLoop1 td

    else liftIO $ putStrLn "We stop"

testLoop1 td =  runStateT (loop1 ) td   >> return ()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that when you type `y` and hit enter, that's actually typing *two* characters: `'y'` itself, and the newline character that gets sent by pressing the return key. The first time round, the loop sees the `'y'`, but the next time round, it sees the `'\n'`, and since `'\n'` isn't `'y'`, it exits.

You can either do `hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering` before you enter your loop (you'll need to import `System.IO`), which will let you process characters without waiting for a newline, or specifically process lines at a time:

```
continue = do
  putStrLn "Do you want to continue? (y/N)"
  s <- getLine
  return $ s == "y"
```

By the way, instead of writing `liftIO $ testLoop1 td`, you can just stay in the same state monad: you can replace it with `loop1` and it'll work exactly the same.

Also, `testLoop1` is better written as:

```
testLoop1 = evalStateT loop1
```

`evalStateT` is like `runStateT`, but doesn't include the final state, so you don't have to explicitly discard the value with `>> return ()`.

Comment: Thanks exactly what i wanted and more. I was on the path finding when i just changed the code and  added a print s that shows the `\n`.                                                                 Thanks for the tip on liftIO $ testLoop1 td -> loop1. That was one of my previous test  and i was wondering which of those two codes to replace.              And good point with evalState. That was my first incursion with statetransformer and IO.